# How do i remove from ESB a message in queue when quality attempts ends

Tags: wso2, jms, messagebroker, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.9 together with the Message Broker for guaranteed delivery a message.
My messageProcessor sends a message to the Proxy Service in which i do transformation message and send to the remote service.

```
<messageProcessor
  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor"
  messageStore="CyberPalt_JMS_MS" name="CyberPlat_ProcsessAddPayment"
  targetEndpoint="CyberPlat_JMSEp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
  <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">2</parameter>
  <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
  <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
  <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>

<endpoint name="CyberPlat_JMsEp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <address trace="disable" uri="http://itprog3:8280/services/CyberPalt_JMS_MsProxy"/>
</endpoint>

<proxy name="CyberPalt_JMS_MsProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <xslt key="request_xslt" />
      <send>
        <endpoint key="testRemoteEp"/>
      </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

But when quality attempts ends, the message remains in the queue.
How do i remove a message in queue when quality attempts ends?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of "max.delivery.drop" in your MP configuration to enable it

Comment: Yes, it is works when the endpoint in the messageProcessor, configured on the remote service, but don't work when the endpoint configured on the proxyService and there the message is sent in the endPoint.

Comment: not sure to understand, you said that quality attemps end so I thought that there were no response from your proxy and then, the MP were sending the message again ? If there is an unappropriate response from your proxy service, perhaps should you add a faulSequence or test the message in the outSequence and decide to return an appropriate message : change http status code with <property name="HTTP_SC" value="xxx" scope="axis2"/> and choose a value different from 200 or 500 so that the MP decide this is a fault

Comment: In the faulSequence add <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"/> a message in the queue deleted. Thanks.